# How did this function turn to the other through the laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I was studying for my exam doing exercises, and in one of the questions where you had to use the laplace transform, they transformed this: $$X'(t)=AX(t)$$ into this:$$sX(s)-X(t=0)=AX(s)$$ where $X(s)=L\{X(t)\}$
Could someone explain to me the left side of the second function please? I've been looking at it for an hour like an idiot and cant figure it out...

Comment: The left-hand side is the laplace transform of $X'(t)$. You should be able to find it in the table of laplace transforms.

Comment: use IBP and the transform integral

Comment: @PepperSausage, so I would have to have the table with me to solve this, there isn't a way for me to calculate this without access to this table or more advanced knowledge?

Comment: @JohnFernley whats the transform integral =s

Comment: You *could* manually compute the contour integral of the transform...

Comment: @Arkamis, that won't do, since im studying for an exam XP

Comment: Well, then memorize the table. It's not hard. Only a handful of key formulae.

Comment: I believe that a formula-sheet is given during the exam, and since it's tomorrow, I think I'll have to take my chances and not really memorize them, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment:

The left-hand side, namely $sX(s)-X(t=0)$, is the Laplace transform of the derivative $X'(t)$. You should be able to find it in most Laplace transform tables.

I'll provide a link to the 'proof' and use of it (as there is too much to possibly write here).

http://www.math.uah.edu/howell/DEtext/Part4/Laplace_derivatives.pdf

Comment: thank you. so basically i had to have a table with me to answer this question?

Comment: No, not really. You can do it manually using the definition of the transform: $$(Lf)(s)=\int^{\infty}_{0}f(t)e^{-st}dt,$$ where $f$ is the function to be transformed.
Personally, I would learn the Laplace transform and do plenty of practice transformations then one can always check with the table to see if one is going in the right direction.